# Airflow "none_failed" skipping when upstream skips

Tags: python, airflow

I have a workflow where I have two parallel processes (`sentinel_run` and `sentinel_skip`) which should run or be skipped based on a condition, and then join together (`resolve`). I need tasks directly downstream of either `sentinel_` task to have cascaded skipping, but when it gets to the `resolve` task, `resolve` should run unless there are failures in either process upstream.

Based on the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules), the "none_failed" trigger rule should work:

> none_failed: all parents have not failed (failed or upstream_failed) i.e. all parents have succeeded or been skipped

and it's also an answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55743947/6591849).

However, when I implemented a trivial example, that's not what I'm seeing:

```py
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import ShortCircuitOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag = DAG(
    "testing",
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval="30 12 * * *",
    default_args={
        "owner": "test@gmail.com",
        "start_date": days_ago(1),
        "catchup": False,
        "retries": 0
    }
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id="start", dag=dag)

sentinel_run = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id="sentinel_run", dag=dag, python_callable=lambda: True)
sentinel_skip = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id="sentinel_skip", dag=dag, python_callable=lambda: False)

a = DummyOperator(task_id="a", dag=dag)
b = DummyOperator(task_id="b", dag=dag)
c = DummyOperator(task_id="c", dag=dag)
d = DummyOperator(task_id="d", dag=dag)
e = DummyOperator(task_id="e", dag=dag)
f = DummyOperator(task_id="f", dag=dag)
g = DummyOperator(task_id="g", dag=dag)

resolve = DummyOperator(task_id="resolve", dag=dag, trigger_rule="none_failed")

start >> sentinel_run >> a >> b >> c >> resolve
start >> sentinel_skip >> d >> e >> f >> resolve

resolve >> g
```

This code creates the following dag:

[image: DAG Design]

The issue is that the `resolved` task should execute (because nothing upstream is either `upstream_failed` or `failed`), but it's skipping instead.

I've introspected the database, and there aren't any failed or upstream failed tasks hiding, and I can't figure out why it wouldn't honor the "none_failed" logic.

I know about the ["ugly workaround"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51664755/6591849) and have implemented it in other workflows, but it adds another task to execute, and increases the complexity that new users to the DAG have to grok (especially when you multiply this by multiple tasks...). This was my primary reason for upgrading from Airflow 1.8 to Airflow 1.10, so I'm hoping there's just something obvious I'm missing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Documenting this because this issue has bitten me twice and now I've solved it twice.

### Problem Analysis

When you turn the log level to DEBUG, you start to see what's going on:

```
[2019-10-09 18:30:05,472] {python_operator.py:114} INFO - Done. Returned value was: False
[2019-10-09 18:30:05,472] {python_operator.py:159} INFO - Condition result is False
[2019-10-09 18:30:05,472] {python_operator.py:165} INFO - Skipping downstream tasks...
[2019-10-09 18:30:05,472] {python_operator.py:168} DEBUG - Downstream task_ids [<Task(DummyOperator): f>, <Task(DummyOperator): g>, <Task(DummyOperator): d>, <Task(DummyOperator): resolve>, <Task(DummyOperator): e>]
[2019-10-09 18:30:05,492] {python_operator.py:173} INFO - Done.
```

From this, you can see that the problem *isn't* that "none_failed" is handling the tasks incorrectly, but rather that the sentinel simulating the skip condition is marking **all** downstream dependencies skipped directly. **This is a behavior of the ShortCircuitOperator** - skipping all of the downstreams, including tasks downstream *of* downstream tasks.

### Solution

The solution to this problem lies in recognizing that it's the behavior of the ShortCircuitOperator, not the TriggerRule, which is causing the problem. Once we realize that, it's time to set about writing an operator better suited to the task we're actually trying to accomplish.

I've included the operator I'm currently using; I'd welcome any input on a better way to handle the modification of the single downstream tasks. I'm sure there's a better idiom for "skip just the next one and let the rest cascade according to their trigger rules", but I've already spent more time than I wanted on this and I suspect the answer lies even deeper in the internals.

```
"""Sentinel Operator Plugin"""

import datetime

from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import SkipMixin, TaskInstance
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.state import State


class SentinelOperator(PythonOperator, SkipMixin):
    """
    Allows a workflow to continue only if a condition is met. Otherwise, the
    workflow skips cascading downstream to the next time a viable task
    is identified.

    The SentinelOperator is derived from the PythonOperator. It evaluates a
    condition and stops the workflow if the condition is False. Immediate
    downstream tasks are skipped. If the condition is True, downstream tasks
    proceed as normal.

    The condition is determined by the result of `python_callable`.
    """
    def execute(self, context):
        condition = super(SentinelOperator, self).execute(context)
        self.log.info("Condition result is %s", condition)

        if condition:
            self.log.info('Proceeding with downstream tasks...')
            return

        self.log.info('Skipping downstream tasks...')

        session = settings.Session()

        for task in context['task'].downstream_list:
            ti = TaskInstance(task, execution_date=context['ti'].execution_date)
            self.log.info('Skipping task: %s', ti.task_id)
            ti.state = State.SKIPPED
            ti.start_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            ti.end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            session.merge(ti)

        session.commit()
        session.close()

        self.log.info("Done.")


class Plugin_SentinelOperator(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "sentinel_operator"
    operators = [SentinelOperator]
```

With the modifications, this then produces the intended dag results:

[image: Correct Dag]

Comment: Nice implementation, wondering if you thought about a way to mark ALL downstream tasks skipped via just the one conditional operator?  If I am not mistaken, d, e, and f have to all use the sentinelOperator.

Comment: Thanks! I did think about that - I think what you're describing is actually similar to the default behavior of the ShortCircuitOperator. The way that it's currently set up, when `e` checks for `d`'s state, the all_success trigger rule sets `e` to skipped when `d` is skipped.That let me control the flow through trigger rules. I did do something similar to what you're describing on another project, using branch selection. I attached the snippet, but let me know if you'd like more details: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1910134

Comment: Well, somehow I missed the shortcircuitoperator.  Wow-what an oversight.  This was what i was looking for.  Your operator will almost certainly come in handy for other instances.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead of datetime.now() we should put pendulum.now()

Comment: Slightly dirtier option in case you don't want a custom operator as per my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63270072/1683314

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Airflow. If you'd like it fixed, add your voice to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4453.

Answer (score 0):

Since airflow v2.3.0, ShortCircuitOperator has a new argument, `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules` which can be set to `False` to obtain the desired behaviour.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.ShortCircuitOperator