# Airflow trigger_rule=none_failed not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have a demo DAG, whose source code is attached below.

The dag is quite simple: 
dummy_success >> one_failed >> none_failed

*dummy_success* is a dummy node and would success whatever.

*one_failed* is a task with trigger_rule=one_failed, so it would be skipped in the dag.

*none_failed* is a task with trigger_rule=none_failed.

As explained is the airflow [documentation](http://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=trigger#trigger-rules), the final task would be triggered because all of it's parents is in state success or skipped(in this case is skipped). However, when I ran this in GCP composer, the final task is skipped too.

I'm wondering why this doesn't behave as expected? And what else can I do if I need my task to be triggered when it's parent is success or skipped?

My image version is composer-1.7.2-airflow-1.10.2

```py
import datetime as dt

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='test_trigger_rule',
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=dt.datetime(2019, 2, 28)
)

dummy_success= DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_success', dag=dag)
one_failed= DummyOperator(task_id='one_failed', dag=dag, trigger_rule="one_failed")

none_failed = DummyOperator(task_id='none_failed', dag=dag,trigger_rule='none_failed')

dummy_success >> one_failed >> none_failed
```

Comment: How is the one_failed DummyOperator being skipped?

Comment: The reason I ask is that different operators with skip logic have different behaviors. I worked through something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310698/6591849

Comment: one_failed gets skipped and then none_failed gets skipped too. I've tried to add another dummy node as upstream of none_failed, and then it worked

Answer (score 1):

I tried add another dummy node as upstream of the none_failed task and then it works as expected.

```
dummy_fix = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_fix', dag=dag)
dummy_fix >> none_failed
```

Seems like *none_failed* trigger_rule works only when the task has more than one upstream tasks?